# Hibernate/JPA - do operations on table only if exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for an answer if it is possible or not in hibernate.

What I am trying to achieve is that if a particular table exists in the DB then the application should do all the regular operations with it (which exists in the code - find,save.. etc.).

Else just ignore the table (@Repository) and the fields in the @Entity class, and will skip all the related code.

I have the same question regarding ignoring particular non-existing field of an existing table and the field is annotated with @Column, is it possible to ignore the field if it does not exist in table?

I want to use save method of JPA but which can ignore that field if needed.

Comment: This looks like a really strange design, never heard of such a feature in jpa/hibernate. Just out of curiosity - why do you need this?

Comment: I upgraded the service, an upgrade that required adding a field and a table, and I still want to support old DB model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's impossible because with Hibernate you map a Class to table and the table and all the mapped columns MUST exist.

What you are trying to do is dynamic SQL and there you would need to read the database dictonary to check what exsits and generate the code during runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this also by try&catch?  In case table is missing then do nothing and in case we have non-existing field then try to do this operation with another DTO cloned class but without the field?

Comment: This would leed to bad performance. Throwing exceptions is slow.